# Issue in update Scatterplot with Multiple Series in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement update in [Scatterplot with Multiple Series](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3183403.)

i guess i need to define key element but not sure how to update series.

```
  svg.selectAll(".series")
      //.data(series,function(d) { return Math.random()*35.12})
      .data(series,function(d) { return Math.random()*35.12})
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "series")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
    .selectAll(".point")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "point")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

how to update and remove.
thanks for your help

Comment: Would be the same as for a scatterplot with a single series. Have you seen [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html)?

Comment: i have seen this tutorial, but here we are creating series and then adding the circle, updating the data. Problem is key is not unique. So i am facing issue in updating and removing.

Comment: What do you mean by problem key?

Comment: if you see my code ->data(series,function(d) { return Math.random()*35.12}), i have used random number in key, this works but removal is problem as all entries are assumed unique.